# Read from array two bytes at a time?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, byte

I declare an array

```
uint8_t data_buffer[64];
```

I write into it, and then I need to iterate over it looking at the data it stores. The data is written in groups of two.

Right now I am doing something messy like this

```
for(int i = 1; i < BUFFER_LEN + 1; i += 2)
{
    if(data_buffer[i] == 0xff && data_buffer[i+1] == 0xff)
    {
        write_led_states(i/2 + 1, OFF);
    }
    else
    {
        write_led_states(i/2 + 1, ON);
    }
}
```

But I'd much prefer to be able to read two bytes of data at a time from the buffer so I could do something more like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < BUFFER_LEN + 1; i++)
{
    if(data_buffer[i] == 0xffff) // where data_buffer is being read two bytes at a time
    {
        write_led_states(i, OFF);
    }
    else
    {
        write_led_states(i, ON);
    }
}
```

Another way of saying what I want to do is to remap the indices so they go from looking like this:

```
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
```

to like this:

```
[1...][2...][3...][4...]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your current code seem to me  like accessing array out of bounds. You know arrays are 0-based, don't you?

Comment: The first byte of the buffer is not used? (`data_buffer[0]`)

Comment: The first byte of the buffer contains a flag noting the type of data that follows. But I suppose yes, I am going out of bounds at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
uint8_t data_buffer[64];
```

to this:

```
uint16_t data_buffer[32];
```

[`uint_16_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) uses 2 bytes (16 bits) per element (and adjust the size to half of 64).

---

PS: Your code seems to access an array out of bounds, which invokes *Undefined Behavior*, here:

```
for(int i = 1; i < BUFFER_LEN + 1; i += 2)
```

Array indexing starts from 0, so this should start from 0 and the condition should be `i < BUFFER_LEN`.

However, with my appraoch, you don't need to increment by two, so you simply do a clean for loop, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; ++i)
```

Comment: There may be a big/little endian problem here. Did you check that?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, why? he is checking for `0xffff` which happens to be the same representation in little/big endian.

Comment: @LuisColorado, If it would only concern `0xffff` then there would be no problem. Would that only be one use or example then there may be a problem which is not covered by the solution, nor does the solution indicate this assumption/limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `uint16_t` instead, which is 2 bytes per element,

```
uint16_t data_buffer[32];
```

be careful with endianness if it can be a problem.

**Note**: it appears that you don't know that arrays are 0 indexed, so

```
for (int i = 1; i < BUFFER_LEN + 1; i += 2)
```

shoul probably be (*most likely*),

```
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; i += 2)
```

And in case you do what I suggest, then each element is 2 bytes so you'd need half the number of elements and of course you would increment `i` by 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two `uint8_t` elements into a single `uint16_t` by bhtshifting:

```
for (int i = 1; i < BUFFER_LEN + 1; i += 2) {
    uint16_t pair = data_buffer[i] << 8 | data_buffer[i+1];
    LEDState newLEDState = (pair == 0xffff) ? OFF : ON; // replace "LEDState" with the proper type
    write_led_states(i/2 + 1, newLEDState);
}
```